# GUI application for controlling Samsung Smart TV connected to the same LAN of ubuntu desktop

Tags: software-recommendation, samsung, remote, smart-tv

I noted that there are no questions about this, and it's sounding very strange.
Anyway, I know the **gemote** project has been abandoned, so I'm wondering if anything similar has been developed.
In brief, I would like to have a remote controller app in my Ubuntu PC to control my Samsung Smart TV connected to the same local network.

Comment: I found [samsung-remote](https://github.com/natalan/samsung-remote) (nodeJS module) and [samsungctl](https://github.com/Ape/samsungctl) (python application), not sure how well they work with modern TVs, though.

Comment: I'm searching something with a GUI... Could you imagine a command line client while you're watching the TV? :)

Comment: @jasmines then please mention that in your question. We can't help if you don't specify what your requirements are.

Comment: @jasmines I couldn't imagine using a GUI on a computer either. I'd probably use my smartphone for that purpose. Or maybe a gamepad connected to a computer, which is where the python library could be useful. As terdon said, please [edit] your question and be more specific about your requirements and the intended use case.

Comment: @jasmines could you edit your question to specify which functions of TV you want to control and why you to use computer instead of smartphone or classic remote control?

Answer (score 4):

You can use YAD to create GUI front end to CLI commands.

As a comment points out there is a CLI controller for the Samsung Smart TV:

- https://github.com/Ape/samsungctl

You just need to install Yad with `sudo apt install yad` and create a GUI window like this:

[image: yad remote control]

Using this command:

```
yad --title "Remote Control" --text "Samsung Smart TV" --width 250 --height 400 --form --columns 2 --field "Power:FBTN"  --field "Vol +:FBTN" --field "Vol -:FBTN" --field "Input:FBTN"  --field "Chan +:FBTN" --field "Chan -:FBTN"
```

Additional code is required to link each button to the Samsung Control program:

```
samsungctl --host <host> [options] <key> [key ...]
```

If I had a Samsung Smart TV I would enjoy writing the full script. However my Smart TVs are Sony and Toshiba. I will try to write a remote control GUI script soon for those TVs.

---

#### Seeing it in action

I created a little demo where instead of calling the Samsung Smart TV commands are echoed to the screen.

[image: yad TV remote controller.gif]

The one-liner code is a little longer now:

```
yad --title "Remote Control" --text "Samsung Smart TV" --width 250 --height 400 --form --columns 2 --field "Power:FBTN" 'bash -c "echo Power"'  --field "Vol +:FBTN" 'bash -c "echo Volume Up"' --field "Vol -":FBTN 'bash -c "echo Volume Down"' --field "Input:FBTN" "bash -c 'echo "Input"'"  --field "Chan +:FBTN" 'echo "Channel up"' --field "Chan -:FBTN" 'bash -c "echo Channel Down"'
```

As mentioned in comments if you have a Samsung TV newer than 2016 you will also need to download the [`websocket-client`](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client)

Comment: please, provide an example with a working link binding...
I tried       --field "Power:FBTN:samsungctl --host 192.168.1.117 KEY_POWEROFF"
      --field "Power:FBTN" samsungctl --host 192.168.1.117 KEY_POWEROFF
nothing works...

Comment: samsungctl is not a valid option, it seems newer TVs are not supported...

Comment: @jasmines I've added new code with button links and information on newer Samsung TVs

Answer (score 0):

yad --title "Remote Control" --text "Samsung Smart TV" --width 250 --height 400 --form --columns 2 
--field "Vol+:FBTN" 'bash -c "echo volume UP && samsungctl --host 192.168.1.5 KEY_VOLUP "'  
--field "Vol -":FBTN 'bash -c "echo Volume Down && samsungctl --host 192.168.1.5 KEY_VOLDOWN"' 
--field "Chan +:FBTN" 'bash -c "echo Channel UP && samsungctl --host 192.168.1.5 KEY_CHUP"' 
--field "Chan -:FBTN" 'bash -c "echo Channel Down && samsungctl --host 192.168.1.5 KEY_CHDOWN"' 
--field "ListCH -:FBTN" 'bash -c "echo List Channel && samsungctl --host 192.168.1.5 KEY_CH_LIST"' 
--field "Ret -:FBTN" 'bash -c "echo Exit && samsungctl --host 192.168.1.5 KEY_EXIT"'